# Envio automático de e-mail com Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, envio-de-email, google-sheets

Tenho esta função no *Google Apps Script*:

```js
function email() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var destino = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var assunto = sheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var mensagem = sheet.getRange("B5").getValue();
  MailApp.sendEmail(destino, assunto, mensagem);
 }
```

Ela envia sempre que executo o Script, gostaria de alguma ajuda para saber como posso adicionar um function para que o e-mail seja enviado sempre que uma linha for preenchida na planilha.

Answer (score 0):

## Utilize Triggers (Acionadores / Gatilhos)

### O que são Triggers?

Triggers (traduzidos como Acionadores ou Gatilhos em algumas páginas da documentação) são uma feature que permite que determinadas funções sejam executadas quando condições especificadas forem atendidas.

As funções executadas sempre recebem 1 argumento, um Objeto que representa o evento que ativou o Trigger, comumente representado pela letra `e`. Pra mais informações, recomendo dar uma lida na [documentação](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Triggers podem ser separados em 2 categorias: Simple Triggers e Installable Triggers.

#### Simple Triggers (Acionadores / Gatilhos Simples)

São funções reservadas integradas ao Google Apps Script, executadas automaticamente de acordo com eventos que ocorrem no Container (Planiha, Documento, Formulário, etc.) de seu Script.

Nomear uma função com um dos nomes reservados para esses Acionadores faz com que ela execute quando o evento "gatilho" do acionador ocorrer.

Exemplos são:

- `onOpen(e)` vai executar quando o Container for aberto;
- `onEdit(e)` vai executar quando o Container for editado;
- `doGet(e)` e `doPost(e)` executam quando são feitas requisições HTTP à URL do Script (exclusivo para WebApps).

#### Installable Triggers (Acionadores / Gatilhos Instaláveis)

No painel do seu projeto, na aba lateral, você tem acesso à seção "Acionadores". Nessa seção é possível criar e configurar novos Acionadores, definir suas condições e a quais funções eles serão associados.

É importante notar que funções executadas por Triggers sempre utilizam as credenciais do "dono" (no caso, quem o criou), utilizando as Quotas e Permissões desse usuário.

Pra mais informações sobre essa feature e sua utilização, abaixo vão alguns links úteis:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)